# docker with nodejs(running pm2) with postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, pm2

---

I am new to Docker. I have an application which runs on apache2 and nodejs (running on pm2) with postgresql database.

I am trying to create a Dockerfile and package.json file to the existing project(which mentioned above) but I am not able to proceed further as sometimes I am getting error as npm problem.

I am trying to do it sample nodejs with apache running but I am getting this error ..  curl: (52) Empty reply from server.

My sample Dockerfile is

```
FROM node:4.2.6
WORKDIR  /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
#RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My Package.json is

```
 {
   "name": "pm2",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "Node.js on Docker",
   "author": "",
   "main": "server.js",
   "scripts": {
   "start": "node server.js"
  },
    "dependencies": {
     "express": "^4.16.1"
  }
 }
```

Please help me out

Comment: The line `COPY . .` in your Dockerfile (I assume `.` contains your app on the host), overwrites your `/usr/src/app` folder in the image, so I think your `node_modules` directory gets overwritten in the image. Try to run `npm install` after `COPY . .`.

Comment: I am trying to create a Dockerfile and package.json file to the existing project(which mentioned above) but I am not able to proceed further as sometimes I am getting error as "npm ERR! Failed at the docker_web_app@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-05-08T11_07_55_298Z-debug.log " Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you try to put `RUN npm install` after `COPY ..` in the Dockerfile?

Comment: yes but still the same problem